# How to mark a point on an Apache Echarts chart?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, charts, echarts

I have a line chart and how to mark a point with click and get value of this point?
If I hover the mouse over a point:

[image]

But how do I mark point with a click? I want the mark to stay there and get value of this point.

Comment: Could you please post all the code for your current build here so we can see and work with your code?

Comment: You start by reading the documentation for what ever charting library you are using.

Answer (score 3):

#### Showing the Tooltip on Click

This is actually supported by Apache ECharts out of the box just by changing your chart options.  You want to set [tooltip.triggerOn](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#tooltip.triggerOn) to `'click'` instead of `'mousemove'`. For example:

```
const options = {
  /* ... other options ... */
  tooltip: {
    show: true,
    trigger: "axis",
    triggerOn: "click",
  }
}
```

[Tooltip Documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#tooltip.triggerOn)

#### Accessing the Value

You want to get the value from the tooltip when it is clicked/shown.  For that we use [events](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#events) and add a callback to the [`showTip`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#action.tooltip.showTip) event.

```
chart.on("showTip", console.log);
```

I don't do much Angular so this might not be the best code, but it works!

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { init, ECharts, EChartOption } from "echarts";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: `
    <div id="echarts-container" #chartContainer>
      Content
    </div>
  `,
  // needs a minimum height
  styles: ["#echarts-container { height: 100vh; }"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  private chart?: ECharts;

  ngOnInit() {
    // I bet there is a more angular-specific way to access the element
    const chartContainer = document.getElementById("echarts-container");
    if (chartContainer instanceof HTMLDivElement) {
      this.initializeChart(chartContainer);
    } else {
      throw new Error("invalid element");
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.chart?.dispose();
  }

  private doSomethingWithTooltipValue(value: number, label: string) {
    // we've got access -- now what do you want to do?
    console.log(`activated tooltip with label: ${label} and value: ${value}`);
  }

  private initializeChart(element: HTMLDivElement) {
    const option: EChartOption = {
      // some example data
      xAxis: {
        type: "category",
        data: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
      },
      yAxis: {
        type: "value"
      },
      series: [
        {
          data: [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260],
          type: "line"
        }
      ],
      // show the tooltip on click
      tooltip: {
        show: true,
        trigger: "axis",
        triggerOn: "click"
      }
    };
    const chart = init(element);
    chart.setOption(option);
    chart.resize();
    chart.on("showTip", ({ dataIndex, seriesIndex }) => {
      // TODO: would need to be more specific about the data types in order to lookup like this
      const label = option.xAxis.data[dataIndex];
      const value = option.series[seriesIndex].data[dataIndex];
      this.doSomethingWithTooltipValue(value, label);
    });

    // save chart instance to component so we can dispose of it in ngOnDestroy
    // there might be a more angular-specific way to do this
    this.chart = chart;
  }
}
```

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-adobe-echarts-clickable-tooltip-isy9r?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Okay, it's good for get value for click, thanks. But how do I mark the points I click? I 'd like to something similar like this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sh4o3enL/

So in your solution, if I click somewhere a dashed line appears and I want that line to stay there as a marker and if I click elsewhere the dashed line also appears there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `markPoint` object

API documentation: https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.markPoint

Editable exemple (line 84): https://stackblitz.com/edit/echarts5-log-max-issue-l6ofst?file=opt1.js

You can use as a marker a pinpoint, circle ... or any image (see `markpoint.symbol` in the API).